# Math.pow restricting the calculation to one decimal point

Tags: java, api, decimal, bigdecimal

I am trying to do following calculation in my java class

Math.pow (0.0901 / 12 * (1 + 0.0901 / 12), 356.966667)

I am getting 0.0 as the result. However the expected result is 0.10844

Comment: No, mathematics says it is 0, or probably something like 0.00000000000001

Comment: 0.0901 / 12 * (1 + 0.0901 / 12) is equal to 0.0075647084027(7). If you raise it to a power of 357 you'll get an incredibly small number, below the double's level of precision, that's why you're getting 0.0 as a result.

Comment: Your base should be something like ~0.993779 so that raised at that power would give your expected answer.

Comment: the result has so many zeros: 6.30259 * 10^-758

Answer (score 2):

I am not so sure that your result should be 0.10844. The base number is something like this ~0.00756 and you raise it to a positive power of ~357. This means that for such a big power, you will have many more zeroes after the decimal point. This means you will have a positive value smaller that the one double can store and it will be rounded to 0.0.

Using BigDecimal you will get the following value: ~7.08E-756 for your computation while the smallest positive double value (Double.MIN_VALUE) is 4.9E-324. This means that 0.0 will be your rounded value.

Comment: I tried displaying it with `System.out.printf("%.20f" , Math.pow(...));`, still no luck. I think the OP has mistaken something somewhere.

Comment: The number has too many zeroes after the decimal point to fit.

Comment: Well, I don't think that `float` or `double` support these many places... [Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=((0.0901+%2F+12)*(1%2B(0.0901+%2F+12)))+%5E+356.966667)

Comment: I think the answer is absolutely `0`. I tried the `printf()` statement with `"%.50f"` and `"%.90f"` and all I can see are zeros. ;_;

Comment: Try using a `BigDecimal` for computing the result and then you can get an exact answer. Like I said in my answer, the number is so large that you may need to use a bigger number of digits (760 or bigger) after the decimal point to get a result.